# how do i tag the entire paragraph(or body) as annotation using GATE annie.

Tags: annotations, gate, text-classification

How do i tag the entire body of the text as a annotation(Gate Annie). For example, i am trying to classify tweets. I would like to classify the tweet as positive or negative tweet. Manually tagging it is time consuming. Is it possible to use Jape to do this activity?
the tagged tweets will be used for machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know Tweet polarity then you can write a simple script in any language which will produce something like(xml):

[tweet polarity="X"]this is tweet body[/tweet]

and then later use it as training instance with polarity as a class attribute for ML.